# How do I install psycopg2 for Python 3.x?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm, psycopg2

Just started Python a few days ago and I'm using PyCharm to develop a web application with Django.  I have libpq-dev python-dev packages already installed, but it's still throwing me the same error:

```
./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

which according to Google is the issue that occurs when python-dev package isn't installed.  Note that I'm running the install from within the PyCharm interface for a virtualenv that I created for 3.2 and 3.3 (not sure how to run it from the terminal).  Installing outside of the virtualenv still throws the same error, even when I install it from the terminal with setup.py.  If I run pip install psycopg2 from the terminal, it succeeds, but it installs for Python 2.7. According to their website, they have support for up to Python 3.2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just run this using the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

This way, you could use gcc to build the module you're trying to use.

Comment: If you read my post carefully, you'd notice that I said that I have libpq-dev and python-dev packages already installed and that it works for Python 2.7, but not for 3.x.

Comment: On Ubuntu that gives: ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Comment: In case helpful for anyone else, if you have multiple versions of Python3 you might need to be even more specific. E.g. `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev`

Answer (score 34):

On Ubuntu you just run this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-psycopg2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is giving me an old version of psycopg2 when I run it. Either that or it's missing some extras for some reason.

Answer (score 18):

Another option that seems to provide a newer version of psycopg2 than the one in the `python3-psycopg2` package (at least when I wrote this):

```
sudo apt-get install pip3
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo pip3 install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 1):

For most operating systems, the quickest way to install `Psycopg` is using the wheel package available on PyPI:

```
$ pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Check:

```
$ pip freeze | grep -i psycopg2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
```

This will install a `pre-compiled` binary version of the module which does not require the build or runtime prerequisites.

Or:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
$ pip install psycopg2
```

Check:

```
$ pip freeze | grep -i psycopg2
psycopg2==2.9.3
```

[More](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#quick-install) info about `psycopg` vs `psycopg-binary`.